# Updating technical specifications after requirements changed?

Tags: documentation, deliverables

We are working on a really large project. After we have created the wireframes and wrote the technical specification we started designing, slicing and programming.

Technical specifications were approved by customer. During the development a lot of changes have been made. The question is: **Is it reasonable to update the technical specification every time changes are made during the development of the project?**

Answer (score 6):

> Is it reasonable to update the technical specification every time changes are made during the development of the project?

#### Short answer:

**Yes**, it's worth the time to update the specs.

#### More context:

Technical specification ≠ documentation, **but** often **there is no documentation** at all.

So if changes are made during the course of long project there is no reference if the specs aren't kept up to date. After a while there's a lot of guessing and the only way to find out is to ask engineers to look up the code (which is time consuming and makes them less productive). Or, if there's a system already live and working, it requires running time intense a test on this system to find out about the behaviour.

**If the technical specification and/or documentation is up to date there is no guessing and it makes everyones life easier.** Plus, it makes your company look more professional because you have always a quick and correct answer to the customers' questions.

And **in an ideal world the technical specification is updated before the change** was implemented in the code.

Comment: And, you can't test against spec if the spec is out of date.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is Yes. The documentation **should** always be updated as there are changes from the client side. This will enable you to produce updated documentation in case of any dispute with the client. Also the development of feature and its testing will be more correct and precise if and only if the documentation is always correct.

Outdated specification will lead to more confusion and delay in the development process.